# Has anybody been able to successfully get an Express app running from Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, express, azure-functions

I'm interested to see if anybody has managed this? If so, if they could point me to some boiler plate code?

I've tried running these packages:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-function-express
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-function-express-2
3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-aws-serverless-express

I've also tried running these with & without using the **Serverless** framework all without any success.

No routes that I've set up respond as expected and I'm unable to get any response from the server at all.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of testing I managed to get this working so I created this report / template to help others get started:
https://github.com/ytsruh/azurefunction-express-template

I'm still unable to get this working via the Serverless framework as the template (Serverless template, not the above repo) appears to not be updated to working with Azure Function Runtime v2.

The other things of note, is that the folder structure appears to be very important & opinionated. Eg the function/app must be inside a folder with the associated function.json file. I'll keep searching for a way to resolve this so it can follow a more 'standard' file structure for an ExpressJS app.